# How come this person is still alive?

Tags: supernatural

In Season 10, Episode 3 *Soul Survivor*, when

> Dean is cured, after having died and subsequently turned into a Knight of Hell

Shouldn't he die on the spot, since his body had previously been mortally wounded, to the point where he actually died?

Answer (score 1):

### Not necessarily

We've seen evidence that demons<sup>1</sup> are able to repair some level of damage to their meatsuits:

- When we see Abaddon in season 8's "Sacrifice", she doesn't have wounds around her wrists:

  [image: Abaddon mit hands]

  This, despite the Brothers having left off her hands when we last saw her (though she notably left the sutures around her neck in - maybe she liked the look?)
- In the season 10 episode "Reichenbach", we see Dean cut his palm with the First Blade, and then heal it:

  [image: Dean's papercut]

Although this is something we've never seen another demon do (most of them don't care a whit about their meat), it's not impossible that Dean, sentimentally attached to his own body, simply healed himself.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or at least Knights of Hell, which is what Dean appears to become

Comment: To be fair, Dean was the first demon we know was in it's original form. Most, if not all, other demons on the show were either possessing a human or in their "hellsmoke" form